# Error in compiling opencv program with g++ and clang

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to compile this basic opencv (v-4.4.0) program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include"opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include"opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include"opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include"opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_world440.lib")

bool exist(const std::string& filename) {
     if (FILE *file=fopen(filename.c_str(),"r")) {
         fclose(file); 
         return true;
     }

     return false;
}
 

int main() {
    cv::Mat image;
    std::cout << image.rows << "x" << image.cols;

    try {
        //if (exist("right.bmp")) { std::cout<<"found";
        image = cv::imread("right.jpg");
        
        if (image.empty()) 
            std::cout << "image not found" << std::endl;
        else 
            std::cout << "image found" << std::endl;

        cv::namedWindow("aerowindow", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cv::imshow("aerowindow",image);

        waitKey(0);
    } catch (cv::Exception& err) {
             std::cout << "exception caught: " << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But on compiling via clang it is generating 8 warnings

```
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:249:80: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
enum { CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR_PRESENT         = CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_GENERATOR_PRESENT,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:250:80: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
       CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR_OUTPUT_MODE     = CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_OUTPUT_MODE,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:251:80: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
       CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR_PRESENT         = CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_GENERATOR_PRESENT,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:252:80: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
       CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR_BASELINE        = CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_BASELINE,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:253:80: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
       CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR_FOCAL_LENGTH    = CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_FOCAL_LENGTH,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:254:80: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
       CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR_REGISTRATION    = CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:256:77: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types
      ('cv::(anonymous enum at D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:224:1)' and 'cv::(anonymous enum at
      D:/opencv/build/include\opencv2/videoio.hpp:231:1)') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
       CAP_OPENNI_IR_GENERATOR_PRESENT            = CAP_OPENNI_IR_GENERATOR + CAP_PROP_OPENNI_GENERATOR_PRESENT,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:16:15: warning: 'fopen' is deprecated: This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead.
      To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
if(FILE *file=fopen(filename.c_str(),"r")) {fclose(file); return true;}
              ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h:207:20: note: 'fopen' has been explicitly
      marked deprecated here
    _Check_return_ _CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE(fopen_s)
                   ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\vcruntime.h:320:55: note:
      expanded from macro '_CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE'
        #define _CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE(_Replacement) _CRT_DEPRECATE_TEXT(    \
                                                      ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\vcruntime.h:310:47: note:
      expanded from macro '_CRT_DEPRECATE_TEXT'
#define _CRT_DEPRECATE_TEXT(_Text) __declspec(deprecated(_Text))
                                              ^
8 warnings generated.
```

And on compiling via g++ it is generating error related to mutex but i am unable to understand why because compiler is ok with -std=c++2a

```
  706 | typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:63:1: note: 'std::recursive_mutex' is defined in header '<mutex>'; did you forget to '#include <mutex>'?
   62 | #include <mutex>  // std::mutex, std::lock_guard
  +++ |+#include <mutex>
   63 | #endif
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:707:29: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
  707 | typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
      |                             ^~~~~
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:707:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  707 | typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
      |                                  ^
make: *** [makefile:4: temp] Error 1
```

i am using this as makefile

```
opencv :=  -ID:/opencv/build/include -L"D://opencv//build//x64//vc15//lib" -lopencv_world440 
flags := --std=c++2a -Wenum-conversion
temp: main.cpp
    g++ $(flags)  $(opencv) main.cpp  -o opencv1.exe
```

There is no problem with the path  (// , / , \ , \ i have used them all) , library is also present in the current directory.

Comment: I believe it should be `-std=c++2a`, not `--`. By the way, it seems to be MinGW. What version of MinGW? Basin on [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723798/thread/c267c1f080/) discussion, it appears that there might be problems with particular threading libraries for various versions of MinGW.

Comment: I started getting that same error after switching from `g++` (version 10, from Debian Sid) to `g++-11` (from Debian experimental).  First of all, I think it's a bug in `g++-10`, because that's an error from a system header, which shouldn't trigger.  But it's also something that OpenCV should probably fix some day, so I reported it to them: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20269

Comment: Could you please confirm your g++ version?